# Prepend current git branch in terminal

Tags: command-line, git, prompt, ps1

How can I configure the terminal to display the current git branch?

I'd like to see the second line rather than the first:

```
andy@bob:~/my_projects/project_x$ 
(master)~/my_projects/project_x$
```

*I don't want to have to run `git status` to see which branch I am currently on anymore!*

Comment: Make sure to include whole bash prompt in double quotes. If you put it in single quotes, the value inside parenthesis won't evaluate.

Comment: @user3173748 If you want something in the prompt to be evaluated on usage time, it *has* to be single quoted or at least escaped or it will be evaluated on definition. That aside, there isn't even anything in the question to be evaluated as it just shows, how the prompt should look like and not how it is defined.

Comment: I know duplicates don't have to be older, but it amuses me this 2013 question is closed as duplicate of a 2016 one.

Comment: Here's what the [*git book*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A:-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Bash) has to say about it: "... copy the `contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh` file from Git’s source repository ..." which would be [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh). Further step-by-step instructions are found in the file itself.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can add [the following code](https://web.archive.org/web/20161017130104/http://www.cs8.my/2008/07/make-your-bash-aware-of-git-branch/) to you `.bashrc` file:

```
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$(parse_git_branch) $ "
```

You can move around these component parts to configure to your tastes, for example to prepend `$(parse_git_branch)` and not show the user@computer part I used:

```
PS1="\$(parse_git_branch)${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\w$ "
```

Which displays:

```
(master)~/my_projects/project_x$
```

*See also: [What is this PS1 variable doing in .bash_profile file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186797/what-is-this-ps1-variable-doing-in-bash-profile-file)*

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the brackets and change the color?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach yes, to avoid brackets you just rewrite the PS1 line (without the brackets). For color see here: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html

Comment: Well, I rewrote the `parse_git_branch` method like that: `git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/|\1/'` and added color in PS1 like in your linked tutorial.

Comment: There needs to be a correction to this answer to include the fact that it will display branch if and only if your current directory is a repository. See my post :  http://askubuntu.com/a/766060/295286

Comment: Also see the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) for an explanation of all the magic symbols.

Answer (score -1):

Add this one liner to the `.bashrc`:

```
export PS1='\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " [ - %s - ]") \$ '
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also add the following line to your .bashrc:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\`__git_ps1`\$ '
```

Comment: And what is `__git_ps1`?

Answer (score -2):

This will add color to the branch name in terminal

```
git_branch() {
   git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[1;31m\]'"\$(git_branch)\[\033[00m\]$ "
```