# show git branch in `ls -l`

Tags: command-line, git, ls

Is it possible to configure the `ls` command so that, when I use `ls -l`, it appends the git branch name after the directory name, if the directory is a git repository?

This way I can quickly find git repositories under the current directory as well as their working status.

Something like this:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 michael michael    8 Aug 26 02:07 a-file
drwxrwxr-x  3 michael michael 4096 Aug 26 02:07 a-repo/ (master)
drwxrwxr-x  2 michael michael 4096 Aug 26 02:07 not-a-repo/
```

Note: I'm not looking to show git branch for the current directory or as part of the shell prompt, [which I already know how](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249174/prepend-current-git-branch-in-terminal).

Comment: I'm thinking you'd have to write your own code snippet for this, as I'd assume that *if* one exists, the user who wrote it will not see this, and will most likely not have publicly released it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... Seeing that there is no built-in way to do it, I went ahead and wrote my own Python program. You can get it with pip:

```
pip3 install mklibpy-bin
```

Currently only support Python3.

[GitHub link](https://github.com/MichaelKim0407/mklibpy)

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a little Bash function using mainly `awk` to process the output of `ls` and append git branch names to directories, if they are part of repositories.

#### Installation:

To install the function, simply copy the line below and append it to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file. You have to `source .bashrc` after that or restart the shell session for the change to take effect.

```
lg (){ ls -alF "$@"|awk '{match($0,/^(\S+\s+){8}(.+)$/,f);b="";c="git -C \""f[2]"\" branch 2>/dev/null";while((c|getline g)>0){if(match(g,/^\* (.+)$/,a)){b="("a[1]")"}};close(c);print$0,b}';}
```

After that, you will have a new command `lg` available that behaves like the default `ll` alias (actually `ls -alF`), but with the appended current git branch.

#### Example usage:

Here is some example output, not the branch names in braces behind `git1/` and `git2/`:

```
$ lg
total 48 
drwxrwxr-x 12 bytecommander bytecommander 4096 Aug 26 14:48 ./ 
drwxr-xr-x 74 bytecommander bytecommander 4096 Aug 26 15:30 ../ 
drwxrwxr-x  6 bytecommander bytecommander 4096 Aug 26 14:43 git1/ (master)
drwxrwxr-x  7 bytecommander bytecommander 4096 Aug 26 14:42 git2/ (develop)
drwxrwxr-x  4 bytecommander bytecommander 4096 Aug 26 14:45 no-git/ 
-rw-rw-r--  1 bytecommander bytecommander    0 Aug 26 14:42 regular-file
```

The `lg` command still accepts all kinds of arguments, just like `ls` does. You can e.g. run `lg -h`, `lg ~/projects`, `lg ..` etc.

#### Updates:

- Fixed issue with filenames containing spaces or starting with `#`.

#### Known bugs and drawbacks:

- The output will not be colored unlike the default `ls` output (e.g. directories are blue, executables green, symlinks cyan, ...).
- It can not handle file names with newline characters in them. They will be displayed, but no branch info is shown.
- The `ls` output will always be correct and display information about the path you specify as argument (if any, otherwise current directory as default). However, the branch information for the `./` and `../` entries is always relative to the current working directory, not the specified directory.
- If you run this inside a repository, every subdirectory will also get the branch appended. The function does not distinguish between repository root directories and any repository subdirectories.

If you encounter more problems or happen to know a solution for one of the listed issues, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Filenames with newline characters in them, while technically valid, should be considered 'invalid' I believe.  They tend to break a lot of things :P

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, since there is no built-in way to do it, I'm considering writing a Python program myself, as it can be more flexible than `awk`